# On randomized estimators

Tags: statistical-inference, estimation

I been reading the following text on randomized estimators, I cant manage to understand how the randomisation is incoparated into the randomized estimator.

[image]

How does the random mechanism fit in, where does it appear in the definition of the random estimator?

The answer posted is a good answer, I been updating the question since it was poorly formulated and that might be why the answer seams wierd in relation to the question.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following example.

You have a coin whose probability of landing heads when tossed is $\theta$.  You know the precise and true value of $\theta$.

You give this coin to Experimenter 1, but you do not tell him $\theta$.  He conducts an experiment consisting of tossing the coin $n$ times, and recording the results ($0$ for tails and $1$ for heads) as a vector $\boldsymbol x \in \{0,1\}^n$.  This vector is the **sample**, and it is "original" in the sense that it comprises the entirety of the information gained from the experiment; namely $$\boldsymbol x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n), \quad x_i \in \{0,1\}$$ not only tells Experimenter 1 how many heads were obtained, but also *which tosses* were heads and which were tails.

Now suppose Experimenter 1 now tells Experimenter 2 the value $$T(\boldsymbol x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$$  Experimenter 2 does not flip the coin; he too is unaware of the true value of $\theta$, and he does **not** know which tosses were heads and which were tails from Experimenter 1's experiment.  All he is told is the number of heads and the sample size $n$.

Does Experimenter $2$ have the same ability to make inferences on $\theta$ that Experimenter $1$ does?  If $T(\boldsymbol x)$ is a **sufficient statistic** for $\theta$, the answer to this question is **yes**.

With respect to the "randomization" notion, what the author is trying to get at here is that what matters in regard to the estimation of $\theta$ is not the order in which the heads were obtained, but merely the number of heads observed.  Therefore, Experimenter 2 can use a randomization device to **simulate** outcomes from the original sampling distribution that satisfy $T(\boldsymbol x) = y$.  Concretely, if the coin was tossed $n = 17$ times and Experimenter 2 was told $T(\boldsymbol x) = 8$, then Experimenter 2 can create a simulation of a sample that has $8$ heads and $9$ tails; e.g., $$\boldsymbol x = (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1).$$  Does this mean that this sample was what Experimenter 1 actually observed?  Of course not.  Experimenter 1 could have observed some other sample, but **it doesn't matter**.  That $T(\boldsymbol x)$ is sufficient for $\theta$ is why it doesn't matter.

Now, it is important to remember that $T(\boldsymbol x)$ may be sufficient for some parameter $\theta$, but that does not mean it **estimates** $\theta$.  Sufficiency pertains to **data reduction**, not estimation *per se*.  However, estimators that have "good" properties (such as those that do not unnecessarily throw away information) are usually based on sufficient statistics.

Comment: So this randomization is according to some random variable, which is determined on sample size and distributions in the sample?

Comment: @User1  No.  The randomization device only serves to allow Experimenter 2 to choose a sample that **could have generated** the statistic he was told.  For example, if $n = 17$ and $T(\boldsymbol x) = 8$, then you could list out all of the $\binom{17}{8}$ samples $\boldsymbol x$ for which $T(\boldsymbol x) = 8$, and use a random number table to select one of those $24310$ outcomes.  But to think that there is some parametric distribution underlying this choice is to miss the point of the author's argument.

Comment: But how is $Y$ an observation? do they mean an obervation of $Y$?

Comment: @User1 In the author's text, $\boldsymbol Y$ refers to a vector-valued random variable from the same sample space as $\boldsymbol X$.  The author is basically saying that given the sufficient statistic $T(\boldsymbol x)$ from an **observed** outcome, Experimenter 2 can randomly generate some outcome $\boldsymbol y$ such that $T(\boldsymbol y) = T(\boldsymbol x)$, and that the distribution of $\boldsymbol Y$ from which $\boldsymbol y$ is taken is the same as the distribution of $\boldsymbol X$, the actual distribution.

Comment: ok, well whats our randomised estimator in this case? It should be an r.v taking x and via T gives us an r.v depending on x? Thats why I talked about  r.v in my first comment, not in some parametric model but completely detemined by T=t.

Comment: There is no "randomized estimator."  There isn't even necessarily an **estimator**.  All that the author has been discussing is **sufficiency**, and as I said in my answer, sufficiency pertains to data reduction.  As you can see in the example I provided, the statistic $T(\boldsymbol x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is not, in itself, an estimator of $\theta$, since $T(\boldsymbol x) \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, whereas $\theta \in (0,1)$.  A sufficient statistic need not estimate $\theta$.  It only needs to preserve all the information about $\theta$ that was in the original sample.

Comment: Im sorry you are right its not mentioned, but obe often wants to base any estimator on this sufficent statistic using via the conditional. And thats whats a random estimator I guess.

Comment: The author hasn't gotten to the chapters about estimation yet, **and there is a very good reason why**.  Do yourself a favor and try not to read this part of the chapter with point estimation in mind.  Data reduction is the topic.  Although estimators are the eventual goal, it is important to understand why estimators derived from (minimal) sufficient statistics are in some sense "good" estimators; but if you read this early part of the chapter trying to tie $T(\boldsymbol x)$ to an estimator, you will only confuse yourself.

Comment: An estimator is a **statistic**.  It is a function of one or more random variables, and therefore is itself a random variable.  But you have taken the author's words and created your own terminology of a "randomized estimator."  This is not what the author stated.  The statistic of interest in this section is the **sufficient statistic** $T(\boldsymbol x)$.

Comment: actually, I been trying to read this in Lehmanns "Theory of point estimation" , but I didnt get what he meant there thats why I went to this softer source. I can paste in whats there aswell. He does it all at once..